# How to convert JSON Date to Month in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have JSON Data from my Appscript REST API, how can I convert the date to be a month in number eg if the date contains 01 I only obtain 1/or instead of "2020-01-15T22:00:00.000Z

Here is the data sample below:

```
{
"Employee Name":"Ntombi  Hlatshwayo",
"Issueing Manager":"Nomsa Nxumalo",
"Type Of A Warning":"Insubordination Final",
"Date":"2020-09-15T22:00:00.000Z",
"Current Date":"2021-11-02T12:24:32.428Z",
 "Status":413
}
```

Comment: What is a "month in number"? Do you want to convert the date to a string that represents the month as a single number without a leading zero?

Comment: Please update the question with what is the expected output for the current input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Date() constructor to parse the dates since they are in ISO format, then use getUTCMonth() to get the month *index*.
The month number will be one greater than this.

You can also use `String.split()` to get the same value.

```js
let o = {
    "Employee Name":"Ntombi  Hlatshwayo",
    "Issueing Manager":"Nomsa Nxumalo",
    "Type Of A Warning":"Insubordination Final",
    "Date":"2020-09-15T22:00:00.000Z",
    "Current Date":"2021-11-02T12:24:32.428Z",
     "Status":413
}

function getMonthFromISODate(dt) {
   return new Date(dt).getUTCMonth() + 1;
}
 
console.log('Using Date()');
for (let dt of [o.Date, o['Current Date']]) { 
    console.log(`Date: ${dt}, Month: ${getMonthFromISODate(dt)}`);
}

function getMonthFromISODateII(dt) {
   return +dt.split('-')[1];
}
 
console.log('Using String.split()');
for (let dt of [o.Date, o['Current Date']]) { 
    console.log(`Date: ${dt}, Month: ${getMonthFromISODateII(dt)}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```